# Add new admin user to MySQL

Tags: mysql, windows-server

I have inherited a `MySQL` instance currently being used by an enterprise software suite. I have no idea what the credentials are for any account, but have full admin rights to the server that the instance is installed on.

I am not very knowledgeable about `MySQL`. Is there any way I can either add a new admin user or find out the details of an existing user of some kind?

I have looked in what seems to be the `my.conf` file I think is being used, but there are only various directories and server ports being set there.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into resetting the root password.
Normally the root user shouldn't be used for any enterprise package, however "shouldn't" isn't much of a guarantee.

Your first action SHOULD be to ask around for the root password or look in whatever password storage your company might be using.

If all else fails and you have to reset the passwored, you can find out how [here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)
Alternatively you could use [--skip-grant-tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708409/how-to-start-mysql-with-skip-grant-tables), and create a new admin user, however this is very insecure, and would be best done during a maintenance window with restriction of the network access.

Answer (score 0):

**mysql workbench** (download from mysql website) is GUI tool which gives option to manage user account and privileges and many  other administrative operations on database.

If you forgot mysql root password you can reset using --skip-grant-table as Reaces mentioned.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052095/recover-or-reset-root-password) is my post to reset mysql root password.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql username and host define a user. You can have a list of all the users by executing the following query:

```
select User, Host from mysql.user;
```

This will result something like this:

```
> select User, Host from mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| User             | Host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| roo              | 10.%      |
...
```

For every user you can see the grants by running:

```
show grants for 'root'@'10.%'
```

You can add new admin user by

```
GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';
```